# Application level variable in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application level variable in one window

```
  object temp1 = App.Current.Properties["listofstring"];

   var temp2 = (List<string>)temp1;
```

when iam changing lets say

```
 temp2[0]="abc";
```

it also change that in **"listofstring"**

so i made a copy

```
List<string> temp3 = temp2;
```

but if i do

```
 temp3[0] ="abc";
```

it change in **"listofstring"** too when accessed in other window ?

How do i use only **local copy** of it **not disturb** its contents once declared?

Comment: You only copied a reference, you did not make a deep copy. Anyway, my recommendation (which is definitely not the answer to this question) would be: do not use global variables. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not making copy of the list, instead you are copying the reference. You can do:

```
List<string> temp3 = new List<string>(temp2.ToArray());
//or
List<string> temp3 = new List<string>(temp2);
```

Or

```
List<string> temp3 = temp2.Select(r=>r).ToList();
//or 
List<string> temp3 = temp2.ToList();
```

Comment: @uncia, are you sure, clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: @uncia, are you sure your list is List of string ?

Comment: It is of class objects which has all member string

Comment: @uncia, then its a different thing. You have to implement [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx)